# Infinite loop fscanf in C

Tags: c, scanf

I am having problems with fscanf getting stuck in an infinite loop. 
{

```
char num;

FILE *filePtr;

if ((filePtr = fopen("filename.txt", "r")) == NULL)
{
    printf("File could not be opened");
}
else
{
    while (fscanf(filePtr, "%20[^ ,]", &num) != EOF)
    {
        displayFun(num);
    }

}

return 0;
```

The file input that I need it to read is:
0, 1, 2, 3, 16, 17, 1234, 5678, -201, 65534, 65535, 65536, -1

For some reason the code gets stuck in a loop and the first zero and wont continue on to the other numbers.

Comment: Your `fscanf` call will return `1` on success, so compare against that, not `EOF`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't store 20 characters in a single `char`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Comment: @Eiko That is a C++ answer. Please observe the tag system and don't close as duplicates from different languages.

Comment: @2501 But the comments and answer cover c as well.

Comment: @Eiko No tag, no dup.

Comment: You get an infinite loop because when it comes across the comma, `scanf()` returns 0, not EOF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"%20[^ ,]"` never consumes a `,` or space.  They stay in `filePtr` for the next `fscanf()` call.  Code needs to somehow read the `,` and space.

As [@melpomene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38415875/infinite-loop-fscanf-in-c/38415925#comment64239029_38415875) commented, reading text as a string into a `char` will not work,

Recommend to read an `int` and `,` instead.

```
int number;
while (fscanf(filePtr, "%d,", &number) == 1) {
    displayFun(num);
}
```